# Active Record doesn't update collection when there is joins and includes in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Hello I've a problem with my query.
There are my models below:

```
class Owner
  has_many :busiensses
  has_many :adverts
end

class Business
  belongs_to :owner
end

class Advert
  belongs_to :owner
end
```

When I make this query everything is okay and it returns right collection full of needed objects:

```
 Owner.joins(:adverts).includes(:businesses)
   .where(businesses: {owner_id: nil})
```

But when I add to query update it raises error

```
 Owner.joins(:adverts).includes(:businesses)
   .where(businesses: {owner_id: nil})
   .update_all(status: 'sth')
```

Error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "businesses"
```

Where is the problem? I bet this error from SQL and it raised when you forget add *sth* to **FROM** statement and that *sth* needed in further conditions, but where in AR i forgot to add it?

Comment: try to do `.update_all("owners.status = 'sth'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Owner.joins(:adverts)
 .includes(:businesses)
 .where(businesses: {owner_id: 1})
 .update_all(name: "blaaaaa")
```

This statement translates into this query:

```
UPDATE "owners" 
SET "name" = 'blaaaaa' 
FROM "businesses" /* missed this */
WHERE "owners"."id" IN 
 (SELECT "owners"."id" FROM "owners" 
 INNER JOIN "adverts" 
 ON "adverts"."owner_id" = "owners"."id" 
 WHERE "businesses"."owner_id" = 1)
```

You miss the `"FROM 'bussinesses'"` which causes the error:

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "businesses"

My solution is to use `joins` instead of using `includes`. It works fine in my machine.

```
Owner.joins(:adverts)
 .joins(:businesses)
 .where(businesses: {owner_id: 1})
 .update_all(name: "blaaaaa")

=> 1
```

Comment: This is nice solution but my primary goal was to find the collection of owners to update, I solved the problem by this query: 
`Owner.joins(:adverts).joins('left outer join  businesses on owners.id =  businesses.owner_id where businesses.owner_id is NULL').distinct.update_all(source: 'sth')`